# Marketing Cloud Connector Error Message After Connecting to Sales CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

The following actions failed and should be performed manually to complete your marketing cloud configuration. Please refer to help.salesforce.com for instructions.

```
Email Send Scheduled Send Workflow : IO Exception: Read timed out
Mobile Send Backup Workflow : IO Exception: Read timed out
Mobile Send Scheduled Send Workflow : IO Exception: Read timed out
Triggered Send Backup Workflow : IO Exception: Read timed out
```

What are the potential problems causing this?

Comment: Was there any solution for this, I receive mobile send schedule send workflow: IO Exception: Read Timed out marketing cloud aswell.

Comment: @RobSource went back and redid the entire connector process, there was a setting that was not enabled and it fixed the error issues. Make sure you're meticulous about it on both sides (Sales & MC) and it should work after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Went back and redid the entire connector process, there was a setting that was not enabled and it fixed the error issues. Make sure you're meticulous about it on both sides (Sales & MC) and it should work after.

Comment: Please share with us which setting it was. It might save other people time when dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same error after configuring MC Connect. I went over the configuration to make sure all steps were followed correctly, and noticed that SFDC needs a little bit of time to finish all the automated processess.

After 5-10 minutes I went to the Marketing Cloud tab in SFDC, clicked on "Connect to Marketing Cloud" (it did not show me any alert this time) and it connected with no fuss at all.

I would definitely re-check the configuration steps if this happens again, and if everything seems fine give it some time to finish those automated processess.